# Google Cloud Platform - load balancer websocket keep disconnecting after few seconds

Tags: websocket, socket.io, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

We are using 2 servers and have setup load balancer to redirect the trafic. Both servers are Compute engines.

We are also using websocket (socket.io) to keep the connection between users (online and offline status). When connection is established between users, it gets disconnected after few seconds. We concluded that it is load balancer configuration issue as if we use single server (without load balancer), connection remains alive until user goes offline.

We need help here if we need to do anything extra in load balancer configurations to work it smoothly with websocket.

Using ip addresses, not domain name (if that makes any difference)

Comment: Does https://serverfault.com/a/888629/237831 help?

Comment: Does it close after a few seconds or after 30 seconds. This issue is usually related to the [backend timeout](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/http/backend-service#timeout-setting). Can you try to set the timeout to the maximum allowed value, which according to the API documentation is 86400 seconds (24 hours)? Please be sure to wait a few minutes to confirm if it works, as the change needs to propagate globally.

Comment: Oliver, that is specific nginx issue. At our server node is installed, thank you for looking into it.

Comment: Watercroft, it got disconnect after 3,4 seconds, some time 7,8 seconds. It is not timeout issue as timeout is already set to 30 seconds. Plus i have tried increasing that timeout. I am still unable to resolve that. Thank you for looking into it.

Comment: I believe this should go through a support case. As there is no special configuration or workaround for the issue.

Comment: @Watacroft - You sir, are my hero!

Comment: Did you solve it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by applying the following steps:

1. BackendConfig
2. Annotate nginx time out params in ingress.yaml
3. Annotate your service with backend-config directive.

Lets see how:

1. Create `BackendConfig`

```
kind: BackendConfig
metadata:
  name: backend-config
spec:
  timeoutSec: 3600
  connectionDraining:
    drainingTimeoutSec: 3600
```

2 . Annotate your `ingress.yaml`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-static-ip
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: cert-name
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3600"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-http-version: "1.0"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/connection-proxy-header: "keep-alive"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: 'fancy.hostname.io'
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

3. Annotate your `service.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
  labels:
      app: my-service
  annotations:
    # Add this annotation to annotate your sservice with the backend config
    cloud.google.com/backend-config: '{"ports": {"80":"backend-config"}}'
spec:
  selector:
    app: your-app-name/deployment-name
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    name: your-app-name/deployment-name
  type: NodePort
```

After applying all these steps i was able to keep the websocket open for one our which was closed by Google Load Balancer's 30 seconds default timeout.

Hope this solves your problem.